# Using std::cin makes std::vector::push_back fail on msvc, but not on clang

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang++

I have a `Graph` class like the following:

```cpp
struct Graph
{
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<uint16_t>> _edges;
    uint16_t                           _numVertices;

  public:
    Graph(uint16_t numVertices) :
        _edges(numVertices),
        _numVertices { numVertices }
    {}

  public:
    void AddEdgeByOneBasedIdx(uint16_t vertexFrom, uint16_t vertexTo)
    {
        assert(vertexFrom != 0 && vertexFrom <= _numVertices);
        assert(vertexTo != 0 && vertexTo <= _numVertices);

        _edges[vertexFrom - 1].push_back(vertexTo - 1);
    }
};
```

and the program throws an exception in `std::vector::capacity` called in `std::vector::push_back` in `Graph::AddEdgeByOneBasedIdx` like the following:

[image]

This was the call stack when the exception was thrown:

[image]

this was the input:

```
3 2
3 2
1 3
```

and the main function was like this.

```cpp
int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    uint16_t numVertices;
    uint32_t numEdges;
    std::cin >> numVertices >> numEdges;

    Graph graph { numVertices };
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numEdges; ++i)
    {
        uint16_t vertexFrom, vertexTo;
        std::cin >> vertexFrom >> vertexTo;
        graph.AddEdgeByOneBasedIdx(vertexFrom, vertexTo);
    }
}
```

I saw the disassembly window and found that the generated assembly code is wrong.

[image]

The generated assembly code has `call rax`, which is used when a function pointer is called. I tried several examples, and found that using `std::cin` makes MSVC generate wrong assembly code. When the main function is like the following, the program runs well.

```
int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::istringstream iss { "3 2\n3 2\n1 3" };
    // std::istream&      is = std::cin;
    std::istream& is = iss;

    uint16_t numVertices;
    uint32_t numEdges;
    is >> numVertices >> numEdges;

    Graph graph { numVertices };
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numEdges; ++i)
    {
        uint16_t vertexFrom, vertexTo;
        is >> vertexFrom >> vertexTo;
        graph.AddEdgeByOneBasedIdx(vertexFrom, vertexTo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I wonder whether my code is wrong, or there was a known bug. This does not happen when I use clang. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.7 and clang 10.0.0 on Windows 10 20H2. Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Fyi, using the provided input your failure case code... doesn't (fail) with msvc.14u3 (i.e. vs2015, update3) with native libraries on Windows 10 Pro 19041.517. (tested both debug and release with full optimizations).

Comment: After having looked for an obvious bug which I couldn't find, I copied your code and compiled it on my local VS 2019. It ran without any issues (as I somehow expected). I don't understand how this can happen in your case... Two (desperate) ideas: 1. Are you sure that your SDK is intact? 2. Are you sure that intermediate and/or binary files of clang and msvc doesn't get mixed up? I use CMake where we always have a separate build directory. This prevents us from such annoying/confusing effects.

Comment: cannot reproduce on https://rextester.com with msvc 19.00.23506

Comment: @Scheff I repaired Visual Studio and now the problem is fixed. Seems like my SDK was not intact. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

~~I repaired Visual Studio and now the problem is solved. Seems like the SDK was not intact.~~

Edit:

The same error occurred again after I repaired my SDK. I reinstalled Visual Studio and the same error pops up again. I can't figure out the reason, so I'm switched to clang 11.